# Good seed for Java random - Constructing a Maze

Tags: java, random

I am trying to make a program to construct a Maze (a classic exercise in Java) and I want to my method to generate the maze to recieve a seed for the aleatory number generator that is used to generate this. This is required because I want the program to generate the same maze everytime I enter the same seed.
But, with some seed values, more values looks like to have more probability than others.

I mean, suppose that I set a random object with a given seed and use it to generate integers between [0, 4) and this is used as criteria to build the maze. The sequence generated is so characteristic that the maze is just too easy. Is I just dont set any seed, a good maze is generated.
The integers part are just an example. I could use an uniform and divide it 4 regions: [0, 0,25), [0,25, 0.5), [0.5, 0.75), [0.75, 1)

Is there a way to modify that seed so that the behavior of the random number generator will be the same for the same seed and mantain the good "mixture" of the numbers? I mean, how can I generate the same numbers setting a seed such that they are evenly distributed in this intervals?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asserting that _any_ explicitly-provided seed will generate an easy maze, or that the specific seed(s) you tried did?

Comment: any provided seed are generating easy mazes

Comment: Could you share the code you use for generating the random numbers?

Comment: I am using  Random rnd = new Random(seed);. When no seed is provided, the maze looks fine.

Comment: I mean for retrieving the numbers from the generator. How many seeds have you tried with?

Comment: I've tried rnd.getDouble() for the intervals and rnd.getInt(4);

Comment: `new Random()` just picks its own seed, and I would think (hope!) that all seeds generate roughly equally-random sequences, so I don't know why providing a seed manually would make much difference. :-\

Comment: I also don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to make sure the numbers are 'random', but uniformly distributed over [0, 1), [1, 2), [2, 3) and [3, 4):

```
Random random = new Random(seed);
int count = 200; // or another number, just how many you need
List<Float> numbers = new ArrayList<Float>(count);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    numbers.add(random.nextFloat() + (i % 4));
}
Collections.shuffle(numbers);
```

Comment: Won't shuffle give me a different result everytime I run the program or it has a deterministic behavior?

Comment: It is not deterministic, you can check the source code of `Collections.shuffle`.

Comment: You can make it deterministic by passing `random` as a second arg.

Comment: @yshavit I want it to generate the same sequence everytime, but uniformly distributed.

Comment: I've found what I was doing wrong: Setting the seed on the method, not on main. Thank you, guys :)

Comment: @Giiovanna Yes, that would do it! If you set the seed each method, that means you're essentially starting the sequence from scratch each time. Rather than setting a sequence of (e.g.) `[4, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4 ...]` and then saying "get me the next number," "get me the next number," you were re-creating that sequence and reading the same numbers: (1) "get me the first from `[4, 1, 1, 3 ...]`" (2) "ok, now get me the first from `[4, 1, 1, 3 ...]`", (3) ok, now get me the first from `[4, 1, 1, 3 ...]`" etc.